# Особенности объявления внешних ключей в SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Почему атрибут foreign_keys метода relationship требует, чтобы имя таблицы указывалось с большой буквы? Так foreign_keys='[tasks.assigned_to]' (смотри модель) выдаст ошибку

> AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'assigned_to'

при попытке внести данные в таблицу User, хотя таблица и будет создана.
Кроме того, foreign_keys=Tasks.assigned_to (без кавычек) выдаст ошибку

> NameError: name 'Tasks' is not defined

уже при создании таблицы.
А вот объявление внешнего ключа как атрибута поля таблицы срабатывает в обоих вариантах:

```
db.ForeignKey(User.id) #ok
db.ForeignKey("user.id") #ok
db.ForeignKey(user.id) # NameError: name 'user' is not defined
db.ForeignKey("User.id")
#sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with 
#column 'tasks.assigned_by' could not find table 'User' with which to
# generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

Как следует правильно объявлять внешний ключ? **Почему** в первом случае имя таблицы должно указываться с большой буквы и в кавычках, а во втором случае или с маленькой буквы в кавычках, или с большой и без кавычек?

Модель:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    tasks_to_do = db.relationship("Tasks", backref="worker", lazy="dynamic", foreign_keys='[Tasks.assigned_to]')
    assigned_tasks = db.relationship("Tasks", backref="manager", lazy="dynamic", foreign_keys='[Tasks.assigned_by]')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.nickname)


class Tasks(db.Model):
    __tablename__='tasks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    assigned_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    assigned_to = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    state = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `db.ForeignKey(User.id)` - без кавычек это питоновский класс
- `db.ForeignKey("user.id")` - в кавычках указывается имя таблицы
- `db.ForeignKey(user.id)` - здесь указан объект `user`, который нигде не определен в вашем контексте программы, поэтому питон кидает ошибку (определен класс `User`)
- `db.ForeignKey("User.id")` - таблицы с именем `"User"` нет (есть `"user"`)

UPD: У меня работает

```py
import time
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, DateTime, Boolean, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    tasks_to_do = relationship("Tasks", backref="worker", lazy="dynamic", foreign_keys='[Tasks.assigned_to]')
    assigned_tasks = relationship("Tasks", backref="manager", lazy="dynamic", foreign_keys='[Tasks.assigned_by]')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.nickname)


class Tasks(Base):
    __tablename__='tasks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    assigned_by = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    assigned_to = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    body = Column(String(140))
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)
    state = Column(Boolean)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
session = Session(bind=engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session.add(User())
session.add(User(nickname="foo"))
session.add(User(nickname="foo2", tasks_to_do=[Tasks()]))
session.commit()

while True:
    row = session.query(User).all()
    # print(row)
    for r in row:
        print("{}, {}".format(r.nickname, r.tasks_to_do.all()))
    print("\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а что вы можете сказать о foreign_keys='[Tasks.assigned_to]'? Почему не срабатывает без кавычек или с маленькой буквы?

Comment: @jumpjet67 нужно указывать либо объект Column, либо строку вида "[Класс.поле, Класс2.поле4]", например, если объект не возможно достать в текущем контексте питона. Алхимия при декларативном описании схем (как в вашем примере) сама добавляет таблицы в Base.metadata и потом все эти текстовые строки преобразует в объекты питона. (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths)